# Check if a newly created canvas_image is overlapping a previously made canvas_image Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to get an output when `plansquare` is overlapping a new `plansquare` (they are being created every millisecond), but I'm not sure how to do it.
So far, I check the coordinates of the new `plansquare`, and what I want to happen is for it to check if it is touching any other `plansquare`, and if so it will execute `canvas.delete(plansquare)`.

```
def planwallfunc(event):
    press = True
    print(press)
    x, y = event.x, event.y
    def create_rectangles():
        global x
        global y
        global plansquare
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        plansquare = canvas.create_image(x, y, image=planwall)
        plansquarecoords = canvas.coords(plansquare)
        if canvas.find_overlapping(plansquarecoords):
            canvas.delete(plansquare)
        else:
            plansquare = canvas.create_image(x, y, image=planwall)
    root.after(1, create_rectangles)
```

My error is `TypeError: find_overlapping() missing 3 required positional arguments: 'y1', 'x2', and 'y2'` which means it is interpreting `plansquarecoords`as x1. I instead want it to interpret it as all 4 - x1, y1, x2, y2 but I'm not sure what to do.

Anyone know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method requires four positional arguments but you're giving it one argument with four values.

The simplest solution is to use the `*` operator to expand the list of four coordinates into four separate parameters:

```
canvas.find_overlapping(*plansquarecoords)
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped.